# Logic Pro X and Ivory II American Concert D No Sound

Tags: software, logic-pro

I installed Ivory II American Concert D and let me say it sounds amazing. It works perfectly in standalone, however when I try to use it in Logic Pro X, I get no sound from the plugin. Anyone else have this issue and have a solution?

Thanks!